# How do I show that $\dfrac{dE}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t}$ where $U(\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_N,t)$ is the potential energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, differentiation

I'm working through Chapter 1 of *Analytical Mechanics for Relativity and Quantum Mechanics*, and in Section 1.8, they derive the equality in the question. To show this, they claim that

$$\dfrac{dT}{dt} = \sum_{n = 1}^N \mathbf{f}_n \cdot \mathbf{v}_n = -\sum_{n = 1}^N \mathbf{v}_n \cdot \nabla_n U(\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_N,t) = -\dfrac{dU}{dt} + \dfrac{\partial U(\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_N,t)}{\partial t}$$ which implies the desired equality. I understand how they get from the first expression to the second to the third, but jumping to the fourth expression completely bewilders me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Tyler Scott. Welcome to PSE! What specifically is it that bothers you about this equation? It appears to be an expression for mechanical power (energy/time).

Comment: @Drjh It's supposed to be a derivation, but I'm just not sure how they got from the third expression to the fourth expression. That's where my confusion lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the total derivative of $U$ is
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dU}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \sum_n\dfrac{dr_n}{dt} \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial r_n}
\end{align} by the chain rule.  Recognize the last term as negative the third term, as $v_n = \dfrac{dr_n}{dt}$.

Comment: Oh, that was such a stupid mistake on my part. Thank you so much!